# Text Classification from Chatbot

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, nltk, text-classification

I'm just getting started to be a Junior Data Analyst. I applied to a startup and they give me a test. I wonder if someone can give me a hint on how to solve it. The quest are:

Given the random words below (extracted from chatbot):

1. Make a classification plan that presents the themes of the spoken sentence
2. Make a preprocessing data design so that the classification goes well
3. Make a draft of the selected features so that the classification runs well

It belows are Unstructured Indonesian language:

```
Makasii ????
Sekarang jam berapa ya?
Hp gua udah 4g gausah diaktifin lagi
Semlekom
Sejag kapan nama saiia blue (Har Har)
Mana gw tau anying
Nggak bisa di klik
ngga udah
no
Saya Mau Complient ...
Terimakasih istriku
Gk sya udh plih
terimakasih :)
halo mau tanya
Assalamualaikumin
Salam
halon
Yaudah lah
mmm
Suka apa
Makasih ya
Gk jdi
sampai jumpa lagi
gak peka
Ga usah
Bodo amat 
Senang sekali
Ok maya
Sibuk?
nggak inget
Mending taka kemana mana
Mana nih
Samlekom min
Berhentiin
it hole the Herat break losing I am cry
mau komplain
Hii
can you speak english please?
Nggak muncul -mucul
Ga tau mi
mn Ka gak ada soal nya
hmmm
bosen nih
ok..
kamu suka apa
di mana?
kok namanya
Ga dengar
Saya nanya min
Saya mau tanyq
Sudah selesai
Mau nnya nih
Halo
Males dehh
dah mam?
Gak mau jawab
Termakasih
Alaah
Jam berapa ini?
Anjirrr &gt
Ok terima kasih infonya????
Kwkwkwkw
Namamu siapa?
y
Ribet ah
ya terimakasih
Saya milih dimana
ribet anjay
Ah
Waah menarik niih min
Ah gk jls bicara ama lu
Ga guna
tidak, terimakasih
Gak jelas!!!
Terimakasih 
Aduh aku bingung
Mengapa diam saja
Mau nanya dong mi
I love u full
May ku sayang bngt ama kamu
Auw ahh ga bisa saya mahh
Ga ada menu nya mas
Kamu sotta deh
menu mana
Salah klik maya ,harusnya lainnya
sudah makan?
Masntap
Malah milih produk
kenapa namanya
Saya mau tanya ?
Gue udah tau
Bikin kesel ja
Makasih kak
Assalamualaiku wr wb...
Tetap gak bisa
Mbak
kok diam
apa ya
menunya mana
Makasiih
testing
capek deh
bosen banget
kok gitu?
tks
Tak Nyaman
asslamualaikum
terima kasih :)
Mas/mba saya mau tanya
Pgi
Kok ga muncul apa2?
lahir tahun berapa
Okay terimakasih
Sudah kak
Kurang mengerti
Tidaak
Ok dude
ok bye
Permisi mau tanya
gimana ya
Sampun cot
Makan Bang
Yeay di bls :v
alhamdullilah 
mau tanya bisa ?
Assalamualaikumin
permisi mau tanya
Terima kasih
pertanyaan yg membingungkan
Rumahnya di mana?
Dasar boot
Mana menu?
wokee
eh... udah dibilang enggak
Baru sibuk?
Sementara belum. Tq
thanks ya
Pilih yg mna
bosan saya
uhhh
Gak nanya lu maya
mana jawabanya
Hobimu apa
Thanks (love)
Apa kabar?
Meong
nanya berulang ulang
LEMOT EUY
Sumpah ngeseli
Ribet dahh
Hy jg
Barusan Sdh bsa min.. mksh
Ga nyambung jawaban nya
test
Ga jelas bnykn tnya
Saya mau nanya boleh??
Ok thank you
Lanjut Book
Tinggal di mana?
ihhh
Belum ada...
Ngomonge bae cepet
Hei
LoL
thx u
Banyak tanya
Hahahahhahahahaha
Ouy
Sudah, terima kasih
Belom saya cek
Mau tidur ama ayam
Ok mksh
Apaansih&gt
Jaringannya cepet banget dah
yng mana
okei
Okeyv
Tidak penting
Maksudnya gimana ini?
Gausah jwb berbelit2 dah
yaudahlah gpp ttp cantik ko (love)
ok makasih
Mau nanya donk
Lagi sibuk?
selesai.
Kagak nannya namalu
Saya mau menyampaikan keluhan
min di sini sinyalnya cepet banget
Coyyy
Hmmm -,-
jjkakak
Bisa bahasa apa saja?
Gai
Lagi ngapain?
Ga sekolah lu ua
Umur kamu berapa?
Tydak
Ga pernah bgus
sangat baik sesuai program komputer...
link itu gak bisa di klik
Saya ada masalah...
Ra iso nuw kok..apus2
Mana menunya yh kak
Hadeeeeuh
sekarang jaringan nya bagus loh
Auk ahh..
Aku gk tau
Syaa mau tanya
serius?
MAU KOMPLAIN!!
Ga bisa mbak
Ga ah nanti kamu genit
Kalau gini terus merugikan orang
Unchhhh
Gatau diuntung!!!
Wkwkwkwkwkwk 
Saya juga kurang mengerti.
Aku nanya s mba nya jomblo ngga ??
Mana yg dipilih?
Mana? :v
besok ya
Arigato
Hobby nya apa
mana? gaada?
GO
Makasih sayang
Jelek
Cape lah kuya
Siapa kamu?
Saya ingin menyamoaikan keluhan
mana menunya woy?
Gk tau anjeng
Msh aman
Gk tau
Maaf kepencet
saya ingin bertanya
Ribet cukk gue lgi sibuk &gt
Love you may
Menu mna?
uyyy
mlm
Tetimakasih
Kwlwkwkwkkwkwkw
Biasanya g Kay gini
eh
wah menarik ini
met bobo
Left bentar ya
Ngga mau
english?
sedang apa
sekarang sinyalnya udah lumayan bagus
Yaiyalah
Mksdnya apa si
Samlikum min
Masih gak bisa
Boleh nanya ?
mana ya
Saya punya pernasalahan
Kecewa ini saya
umurnya berapa?
Mau tanya bisa
Wah gk jlas
Sudah ada.
Mana ada menu
Bapak kau
Mana menu nya njit
Thanks
Jaringan bagus sekali ya
Apasih ini ga jelas
Ndak tau
Mungkin lain kali
ach ribet amat
Hu
Makasiiihh
Ok!
Min -_- lu sehat?
Gausah ngalem jawab aja kenapa 
Clear
menu yang mana ya
Ribet!
nnti ae
bagus ini
Cepet amat respon nya
oke anjir
Maaf ga bisa d klik
kamu di mana
Kenapa kok maya belum paham sij
Saya kurang maksud atas pertanyaan anda
Zzz
Lagi banyak kerjaan?
Misi min mau tanya
test 1 2 3
Bodoamayttt
Tidak ada pilihan
if lu okay illu
Salah chat kwkwkkw
maksudnya apa ya
Tidak.
Rugi gw belinya
Okee siaap
Min maksudnya
MENU MANA SAJA?
Hi
Thanks sangat ya min
sangat tidak membantu !!!
OK selesai
nggak bisa min
Kgk mau gua
Kami selalu mendukung anda
hadeuhh ribet
fa cai :)
Terimakasi
bingung
Tanks kakak
Mau tanya.bisa?
kalian luar biasa
Detaya :(
Ah sudahlah
Baru apa nih
yaiyalah
Sudah benar
Di mana nih?
menu tidak ada?
SAYA KOMPLAIN
Lagi apa?
Gak
Kok sy ga bisa pilih apa2?
Gak ada. Terima Kasih!
masa sih?
Ah ga ad gunanya sistem bgni
Saya sedang bertanya
waduh
 Hi
gak doyan
Sementara 7 dulu
Jangan muter muter terus mba
Mau nanya ??
Kgk bisa
pacarnya siapa?
Hi hi hi
Mana menunya? Ga muncul, ampun deh
Kagak bisa di pake hhhhhh percuma
Gak berguna
Permisi saya mau nanya
Can u speak english pls
Sudah makan belum?
Aduuhh ribet
Menu nya yang mana
super
gila lu
Gimana kabarnya?
Uda ku isi pak
tes
Ya sudah lah ...
Saya cinta kami
Udah punya pacar?
Sudah tadi.. makasih
Gitu Aja Terus
Oh begitu ya. Terimakasih
Okay terima kasih..
Assalamu allaikum
sialan,,pgn nanya aja dipersulit gini
yang bener?
met tidur
Sedang apa?
dibilang mau logout
Entahlah
Umurmu berapa?
Rumah kamu dimana
sinyal nya bagus
yah -,-
Singkirin bot ini ah
Baru di mana?
Mksudnya gimana sih
Kog menu nya tdk bisa di klik?
hm
Layanan internet selalu cepat
Terima kasih min :)
Kamu siapa?
Saya udah gak ngerti.
Gua mau tdurrr, mlm
Gg tau
Gk butuh informasi produk!
parah ini robot
Makasih ka
Punya anjir. Bacod mulu dari tadi
Terima kasih atas infonya bak
Can you speak English ?
Namanya siapa?
Mana gua tau selesai
```

What algorithm do I need to complete those 3 tasks?

Answer (score 1):

1. Here you need to formulate your problem using the data(if it is provided with test). Identify different themes in data, I do not speak Indonesian so I cannot help with it. But the classification problem could be sentiment analysis, emotion classification etc. In your particular case, I think problem would be different. It will be helpful if you could add the translation of these sentences to your question.
2. You need to preprocess the data so that classifier can perform better classification. In case of English, preprocessing usually involves removal of stop words, lemmatization, removal of any noisy or irrelevant data etc.
3. Select features that you think will be useful for classification. Those features could be the presence of question mark etc. Generally, word embeddings are used for the classification of textual data But the test requires you to select features, so you need to think of some according to your classification problem.

   Edit:
   Once you formulate your classification problem, you can identify the preprocessing steps and features easily and you can apply any classification algorithm such as Decision tree, Random forest, Neural network for classification task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to clarify a little bit:
1. It is not a sentiment or emotional classification. It is basically a random conversation word. Do you think I need to manually classify them or just use the unsupervised algorithm like KMeans or maybe LDA?
2. I can't find any stop words in Indonesian, did I need to build it?

Answer (score 0):

So what I did is:

1. Put those words as csv and load it to list

```py
with open('/content/test.csv') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
# you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

2. Throw it to KMeans clustering

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(content)

true_k = 10
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)

order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

for i in range(true_k):
  print('Cluster %d:' % i),
  for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
    print(' %s' % terms[ind])
```

3. Test it

```
print("Prediction")
X = vectorizer.transform(['makasih istriku'])
predicted = model.predict(X)[0]
print(format(predicted))
```

> Prediction
>   5

Is it satisfied the quest?